# PHP Telnet - send BackSpace

Tags: php, telnet, backspace

I'm using php4 to connect to an old router.

Once the connection is made and I've logged in I send a series of commands..

As I know the output of the router I can answer the questions it is asking directly, so I send :

```
fputs($fp,"Upgrade\r"); // run upgrade command
fputs($fp,"y\r"); // Send y for Yes 
fputs($fp,"\r"); // send return
```

The next line I need to send is backspace 5 times. I've tried

```
fputs($fp,"\^h");
fputs($fp,"\x08");
fputs($fp,"\BS");
```

they all send but nothing is back spacing.. how do I send 5 backspaces to delete the current entry and then I can send my new entry ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging the network traffic when you're doing it manually and seeing what the terminal sends?

Comment: Have you tried "\x7f" for the delete character instead?

Comment: @Mark Baker - That seems to add spaces to the end of the current value, not delete it. I'm sending it as : `fputs($fp,"\x7f");`

Comment: @Orbling - Can you advise how I can do this. I did try tcpdump but wasn't sure what to look at !

Comment: @JeffVader: Depends where it is running, if you're using a shell on the machine that telnet is running on, then tcpdump is what you want.  Look at the [man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), perhaps `tcpdump -l 'host destination.host.name and tcp port 21' | tee dump.dat` - if you did that on one terminal and ran the telnet session manually in the other.  See the [pcap-filter man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/pcap-filter/) for more details on expression.  If you run the terminal on a desktop, there are easier capture programs, like Wireshark.

Comment: @JeffVader: See what your code is doing differently.  You may well find your terminal is applying the backspaces before transmission to the previous entry, or flushing in a different fashion than you are.

Comment: Looking at a wireshark capture I can see I'm sending \b to the router. I've tried `fputs($fp,"\b");` but that just sends \b not a backspace.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending

```
chr(8)
```

directly (no String operations etc.)?

Do you know whether the router uses standard telnet protocol or is it a proprietary (extended) protocol used by some special router management application?

@Comment: I don't believe ASCII code `7` will work as it's `BEL`, isn't it?
See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc137, page 8

Comment: Sorry how do you mean directly ? I have tried `fputs($fp,chr(8));` but that didn't work..